# Mono Embeded in a qt 5.3 application

Tags: c++, qt, mono

I am trying to develop a Qt 5.3 application (MinGW32 on Windows, and Linux Raspbian). I have choosen 5.3 because it is the vanilla version of Qt on Raspbian, and MinGW32 on windows because I don't want to install Visual Studio 2013. Also, I need a WebView, so for simplicity, I use QtWebkit.

It uses [Mono embeded](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/) for some parts of the application.

But I have some problems when building on Windows :

- undefined reference to `mono_jit_init'
- ...

In my .pro file, I have added this :

```
unix {
    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += mono-2
}

win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += "D:\Mono\include\mono-2.0"
    LIBS += -LD:/Mono/lib -lmono-2.0-sgen
}
```

On raspbian, it works, but not on windows.

I am using QtCreator on Windows and on Raspbian.

What have I missed ? Thanks.

Comment: Probably what you need is `-lmonosgen-2.0` or `-lmono-2.0`. See [http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way, on Windows, using Qt on MinGW. The lib file installed with Mono are msvc libs, not compatible with MinGW, so I had to generate my own.

1. download the `mono.def` from https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/msvc/mono.def to `Mono/lib` and rename it to `mono-2.0-sgen.def`
2. in the MinGW commandline, go to `Mono/lib` directory, and run `dlltool --output-lib mono-2.0-sgen --dllname mono-2.0-sgen.dll --input-def mono-2.0-sgen.def`

And tadaaa !